# TCP/IP minimal size

Tags: networking, tcp

I am using a high level language on a PC to send a message via TCP/IP to a remote device which is an embedded device.
I am sending relatively small messages (< 255 bytes).
I must assume that there will be several firewall, proxies and gateway between my PC and the targeted device.
I must also assume that the message could be transmitted by radio (GPRS, UMTS) before reaching the targeted device.

Assuming the hardware and software buffers of the targeted device are big enough (1000 bytes), How small must be the message so that I am sure that it will always be received in one piece at the application level of the targeted device ?

In other words, should I include the size of the message in my application protocol or is it useless since the message is small ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in akira's answer, the minimum message size that a host must accept for IPv4 is 576 bytes, so 255 byte packets should not be fragmented.

However, most hosts today implement [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_Algorithm), which waits 200ms before sending packets to try and group messages. This means that if you send messages in a quick burst, they might be grouped and then fragmented. TCP is not meant for datagrams, but for streams. Boxes in the network might also be doing some strange things (you never know).

I suggest you include the size of the message in your application protocol. This ensures that you won't have problem with TCP fragmenting your messages in a way you hadn't expected, and, as stated in akira's answer, allows you to one day transfer over another media.

Comment: yep. but even WITH nagle (which is just "taking care of the transport") one TCP/IP packet arrives as one TCP/IP packet at the other end (or not), no matter what happens on the way. that's the whole point. (just to emphasize, no critique to your / my answer :))

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to adjust the TCP/IP packet size to the so called [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) (Maximum transmission unit). You can do that. Or you can ignore it and, since you are using TCP/IP just send the packet: it will travel through the net, chopped into pieces and glued together automatically later on and then the packet will arrive.

If your message is pretty small and is below the "minimum datagram size" then this quote will make you happy:

> The MTU must not be confused with the minimum datagram size that all
>   hosts must be prepared to accept, which has a value of 576 bytes for
>   IPv4[2] and of 1280 bytes for IPv6

So, if your message is smaller than 556 bytes (576 bytes - 20 bytes ipv4 header) it should arrive as one paket.

But even with fragmentation: the receiver gets a complete packet only if all (possible) fragments arrived. Which makes it a bit pointless to "care" that much about the message size to avoid fragmentation.

Aside from the transfer size it may be a good idea to include the message size along the message (You might want to transfer the message over different media as well one day)